# Changing default Internet Explorer Security Zone

Tags: internet-explorer

I would like to set the IE security zone to Medium-high for all *new users* on a server.

This is a standalone machine and ultimately I'll need to script it.  I don't mind making a registry change or updating the local security policy.

I've had some success updating HKCU

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3\CurrentLevel
```

but that only applies to the current user.  I see that it's possible to set IE to only use HKLM for all users, but I would rather not change that.  I want to allow it to continue to use HKCU.

Where is the default key that is used when creating a new user?  Or, can I use Local Security Policy, something like: Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key you're after should be:

`HKU\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3\CurrentLevel`

This won't apply anything to existing users, but should be copied to new local users when a profile is created.

Comment: That seems like it should work.  I tried that previously too.  It doesn't seem to work for me and I just retried a few times.  There isn't a key already at that path so I created a new key with just CurrentLevel, but it didn't take.  I then exported my existing key, changed the patch and imported the whole key, but that didn't work either.  I test by creating a new user and check checking the HKCU to see if the key is different then the original default.

Comment: Interesting. On my Windows 7 machine there was a key right down to that path, even though I haven't done any customising. Hope you have some better luck!

Answer (score 2):

In order to change default behaviour for *new* accounts, you need to edit the Default User profile. However, this is **not**

> HKU\.DEFAULT

As this is the hive for the Local System user account, despite its confusing name. ([MSDN Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/03/02/1786493.aspx))

To edit the Default User Profile, you need to change the NTUSER.DAT from the Default profile directory (Location varies - C:\Documents and Settings\Default or C:\Users\Default etc)

You can do this by using the Registry Editor as follows:

- Run regedit
- Click on the HKEY_USERS hive
- Goto File -> Load Hive
- Select the NTUSER.DAT from the relevant directory
- Choose a Key Name (NB: This has no bearing on anything, it's purely a way to reference the hive while it's open.)
- Expend your new hive and make any changes needed
- Select the root of your new hive Goto File -> Unload Hive (This is important, as the file remains locked otherwise)

This NTUSER.DAT now gets copied to new profiles, and they in turn get all of the settings.